# How Can I Aware Register Spilling via Objdump File?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, cpu-architecture

How can I be aware of register spilling by looking at an objdump file? 
My thought is that it can be done by tracking the stack pointer: moving `sp` beyond function prologue and epilogue, indicates register spilling.

I want to know which lines of codes are doing register spilling. Also, where are the registers restored pointed to global variable, also stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register spilling doesn't require moving the stack pointer, a local variable may be spilled to the stack and constantly used directly from there while still in the current frame, and the compiler would just use the stack frame with its offset instead of a register.

Your best bet is just looking for memory addresses being read and/or written to constantly. This may even happen where there are available registers around because of compiler deficiencies, or inability to prove that no other thread/code unit are accessing some local variable by addr (for example if the variable address is copied somewhere out of scope). In such cases maintaining that variable in memory is necessary.